# Crop UIView Snapshot

Tags: ios, uiview

I'm implementing a custom UINavigationViewController transition, and as part of the animation I want to snapshot and transform the destination UIViewController. However, I want to slice the snapshot and transform the parts independently.

There is a comment in UIView.h that seems to indicate that this is possible and even recommended:

> Creating snapshots from existing snapshots (as a method to duplicate, crop or create a resizable variant) is supported. In cases where many snapshots are needed, creating a snapshot from a common superview and making subsequent snapshots from it can be more performant.

However, I cannot figure out how to actually do the cropping or create multiple snapshots from the common superview snapshot.

Is this possible?

---

Note: I did investigate using `UIView.drawHierarchy(in:afterScreenUpdates:)` to create an image that I can later crop, however this fails during a UINavigationController transition with the following error:

> [Snapshotting] View (0x140853600, MTKView) drawing with afterScreenUpdates:YES inside CoreAnimation commit is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [KMT over at the Apple forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/110843), I found the solution:

[`UIView.resizableSnapshotView(from:afterScreenUpdates:withCapInsets:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622597-resizablesnapshotview)

Passing in the desired cropping rect and `UIEdgeInsets.zero` for the cap insets correctly creates a cropped snapshot.